# How do I Install OpenGapps or MindtheGapps on a Work Profile (Shelter)?

Tags: gapps, work-profiles

Searching for a solution to install OpenGapps or MindtheGapps just on the work profile (I installed Shelter/Island).

I found this, but don't know how to fastboot boot a Work Profile.

```
adb push android.apk /data/local/tmp
adb shell pm install --user 10 /data/local/tmp/android.apk
```

My settings:

Users:

```
UserInfo{0:Owner:c13} running
UserInfo{10:Work profile:1030} running
```

Otherwise, would installing Magisk work and the OpenGapps module for it. If so, how do I flash Magisk for a work profile?

Comment: Setup magisk in the device first as normally as any user would do it first time to root their device. Once done, you would have Magisk app in your device for your primary/admin user. In that app, in its setting change multiuser mode to User independent. Now, install Magisk apk in Work profile. Launch it and it would detect root and act as root access manager for work profile apps.

Comment: Modules and core are however shared amongst all users. So you can't have modules specifically for one user.

Comment: @Firelord I tried it and your right it seems to install the module Gapps for both primary and work profile when you root (individual setting) with Magisk. That does not give the isolation / sandbox I want to use with a few Gapps apps inside of the Work profile. I am on Lineage W/ MicroG - but some of the apps I need use Gapps. 

Any other ideas besides having to buy another device for privacy to use Gapps apps separately?? Is it even possible to install Open Gapps or Mind the Gapps in just the work profile isolated from primary?

Comment: I don't really know. Sorry